# Comma Before "If"

Tags: commas

I would like to ask if a comma is necessary before "if" in this sentence (this one is from the mystery novel I am writing):

> I adopted the literal way of understanding the verse, and if it was written to convey a literal message, I would deduce . . .

Comment: If you mean a second comma to bracket the *and* then no. The comma is there to mark the second phrase off. There will be no confusion if you leave out a second one. In reading it out loud it will flow properly with only one.

Comment: If you do use one, remove the comma before _and_.